# How to play a transparent mp4 video (video with apha channel) on .net

Tags: vb.net, video, transparent

I have a video looks like this but its a video. Black background with colored image at top and white image at bottom. When video plays on browser, I see both on movement.

[image]

I have searched long time about how to play the video with transparent background with vb.NET (or C#) without success.

The video was created with an alpha channel, like this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qOhDErn36J0

Please, can someone give a bit of light about this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you try to play with media element or something else like by importing any 3rd part lib. What error you are facing when playing with .net . please describe in details.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have not tryed yet as i dont know hwo to manage this video... can i play as a normal video? when i play it with vlc, i do not see transparent video. i see a video like in the image. With 2 parts in movement. One on color and one more in white with black background...

Comment: mp4 can't be transparent. You could try it with a .gif

Comment: the video has a alpha channel.
https://medium.com/@quentinfasquel/ios-transparent-video-with-coreimage-52cfb2544d54

Comment: here is how the video is created: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qOhDErn36J0

Comment: @PedroTeruelTeodoro a mp4 video still can't be transparent. What you see in the video is alpha channel filter which was added by code. On iOS devs can use the AVFoundation for it. vb.net don't have a alternative.

Comment: Thanks for your response. How then this kind of videos can be used in websites on browsers? look at this url: https://es.istripper.com/model/show/f0278 its a mp4 video with alpha channel

Comment: The one main reason as i think may be that most of the players has background windows. I mean to say that any media element that is fit on the window like other controls. The second big thing is that sometimes controls have their own backgrounds because they are also kind of sub windows. If you are try to play a transparent video which means each frame in the video is transparent then it is important to notice that the video player element(control which play the video) also have some transparent background to handle transparent video. Then the effect will be visible to user.

Comment: here is a sample for html5. http://jakearchibald.com/scratch/alphavid/   is there any way to use on and desktop app on windows?

Answer (score 1):

**This answer is based on sample provided by the @Pedro.**

As already @Marco Sadowski comment mp4 isn't transparent and that is right. 
Which proves from this image :

[image: Sample Video]

Here we can notice few things :

1) Only the html background changes when we click on random color button, the video background remains as black.

2) When you will right click on this you will see save video option (I am using chrome) as we see in next image.

[image: sample vid]

And this video download. When the user try to play with VLC or any other player he/she will see only black background.

**NOW the question is about this :**
[image: Samples]

**Is this is a transparent video : NO**

**Why ?**

Let's right click on this and see the effect :

We see :

[image: Samplle]

**The trick is that :  these are transparent images (with alpha channel) not a mp4 video. These images are changing their frame rate with speed and looks like a video.**

You can write click and save image directly.

**When you click post-processing then the original mp4 video works and doesn't change background after clicking Random color button as we seen in 1st image.**

Comment: Sorry, but i don't agree. There is a video. But the video is not played as is. Canvas are used to show the result of alpha channel processing. Ok, you can download an image, but this image if the result of the mp4 processing. You can download the video here: https://jakearchibald.com/scratch/alphavid/compressed.mp4 and you can play it with VLC and you will see the 2 parts on the video. UP, colored part. Down, white part, like in the picture i posted at the beginning of the post.

Comment: Please see this video there are some important tools in video description that may be help you. With my best wishes. Link : https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=4W5e6-TSpW0

Comment: thanks. seems the best solution will be do this with unity and AR tools...